# Why does this error occur? An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Tags: java, angularjs

Stack:AngularJS v1.6.5, java 8, spring boot, tomcat.
After about 1 week of work , the application not response with such an error. Why this happening?

**Frontend**:

```
$http({
             url: 'find',
             method: "post",
             data: { 'month' : $scope.month,'year' : $scope.year, 'payTime' : $scope.payTime,'waitTime' : $scope.waitTime,'scanTime' : $scope.scanTime,'gbNumber' : $scope.hyper}
         })
         .then(function(response) {
 ..
       });
 }
```

**Backend**:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/find", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ReportResponse find(@RequestBody RequestSearch params,
                           HttpServletResponse response) throws DataNotFoundException {
  ...

}
```

**Stacktrace**:

```
2018-04-02 09:37:44.738 ERROR 14912 --- [p-nio-80-exec-9] o.s.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/excel/ExceReport.xls] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false

org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:356) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:815) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:720) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:391) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:369) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:138) ~[spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeContent(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:110) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:102) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
      ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Cause**

> This exception can mean that the connection to the client browser was
>   aborted before the response is fully transferred. It is a harmless
>   warning as it can be due to transient network problems or the user
>   aborts/refreshes the page before it loaded.

**A list of other causes are:**

> The user closed the browser before the page loaded.
>
> Their Internet connection failed during loading.
>
> They went to another page before the page loaded.
>
> The browser timed the connection out before the page loaded (would
>   have to be a large page).

**Resolution**

> This can be ignored, unless there are other issues that are currently
>   occurring. For example, if the your application server is throwing a
>   lot of these, it might be a sign of a performance problem.

Comment: Also can caused by antivirus program on the host machine. I had the same issue years ago with Windows 10 and nod32.